# To remove last two words from a string

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I have sample strings like below,

**abc/def/ghi/test/yvw/syz**

**abc/fed/igh/test_123/wuvacv/zyxh**

I want to get it like below

**abc/def/ghi/test**

**abc/fed/igh/test_123**

So what are the best way to follow for string manipulation

Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to split by "/" and put the words into an array and looping it.but stuck in middle. Here I cant use regex here cas last two words can be anything.

Comment: Why can't you use regex?

Comment: You can use `str = str.substring(0, str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('/')).lastIndexOf('/'));`. By the way, I would prefer a regex solution (as already shown by shmosel.

Comment: "_trying to split by "/" ... but stuck in middle_" - Can you show us your code and what happens when you run it? You may already be very close to a solution and it may be helpful to you, to see how to fix what you already have (assuming none of the existing answers already do that).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regex to match any text between the slashes:

```
str = str.replaceAll("/[^/]+/[^/]+$", "");
```

Or you can split and rejoin like this:

```
String[] parts = str.split("/");
str = String.join("/", Arrays.asList(parts).subList(0, parts.length - 2));
```

Comment: To use regex I cant predict what will come as a string cas that string is varying

Comment: The point of regex is to match patterns without knowing the exact text. `[^/]+` matches any number of non-forward-slash characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`String.lastIndexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-int-) to search for the second to last `/` and then take the substring. Like

```
String[] arr = {
        "abc/def/ghi/test/yvw/syz", 
        "abc/fed/igh/test_123/wuvacv/zyxh"
};
for (String s : arr) {
    int p = s.lastIndexOf("/", s.lastIndexOf("/") - 1);
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, p));
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
abc/def/ghi/test
abc/fed/igh/test_123
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static String removeLastTwoWords(String str) {
    String[] words = StringUtils.split(str, '/');
    return String.join("/", ArrayUtils.subarray(words, 0, words.length - 2));
}
```

In case you do not want to split a string, you could use `lastIndexOf()`:

```java
public static String removeLastTwoWords(String str) {
    int last = str.lastIndexOf('/');
    int preLast = str.lastIndexOf('/', last - 1);
    return preLast > 0 ? str.substring(0, preLast) : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can take.

Keep in mind, the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* parameter *is* a regular expression pattern.

To create a loop that iterates on a *String#split* you can use the following.
It will stop iterating when it reaches the second to last element—using a fixed condition of *strings.length - 2*.

```java
String parse(String string) {
    StringBuilder parsed = new StringBuilder();
    String[] strings = string.split("/");
    for (int index = 0; index < strings.length - 2; index++) {
        if (index != 0) parsed.append("/");
        parsed.append(strings[index]);
    }
    return parsed.toString();
}
```

Output

```
abc/def/ghi/test
abc/fed/igh/test_123
```

If you would prefer to provide a starting and limiting index, you can implement additional method parameters.
The *limit* argument will be inclusive.

```java
/** @param limit inclusive */
String parse(String string, int startIndex, int limit) {
    StringBuilder parsed = new StringBuilder();
    String[] strings = string.split("/");
    for (int index = startIndex; index <= limit; index++) {
        if (index != 0) parsed.append("/");
        parsed.append(strings[index]);
    }
    return parsed.toString();
}
```

Here is an example input and output.

```java
String stringA = "abc/def/ghi/test/yvw/syz";
String stringB = "abc/fed/igh/test_123/wuvacv/zyxh";
System.out.println(parse(stringA, 0, 3));
System.out.println(parse(stringB, 0, 3));
```

```
abc/def/ghi/test
abc/fed/igh/test_123
```

Finally, if your *string* value follows the same pattern, in which the contained value always starts at index 0, and ends on the first-to-last solidus character, you can utilize the *[String#substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))* and *[String#lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int,int))* methods.

The second parameter of the *lastIndexOf* call, here, is an *offset* index.
So, it is locating the last solidus character, and then using the returned index as an offset of another call.

```java
String string = "abc/def/ghi/test/yvw/syz";
int indexOf = string.lastIndexOf('/', string.lastIndexOf('/') - 1);
string = string.substring(0, indexOf);
```

```
abc/def/ghi/test
```